How to create a websocket server that can handle multiple connections synchronize communication between clients
This question have a similar question here. But someone told me to make my own question so here it is.
I have a client-server c# application that I want to port to a web application. The server receives and dispatches data to clients. It updates other clients when another client send a data to the server. This client-server application obviously uses windows socket for this purpose. Just this month I started writing my first PHP project. Generally it is now functioning as per my requirement. Sending data to my web page when a request is received and saving data to my database sent by a client-side script (javascript, of course). Now, my problem is, how can I notify other clients (like my c# application does) when another client makes changes to the database? I have already done a lot of googling and every result that comes up talks about WebSocket. I've just learned WebSocket have been around for a long time but in my case this is the first I came face to face with it.
I haven't tried anything yet as I don't know where to start. After so many searches I landed at this github page which looks beautiful to me. But one thing that came immediately to my concern is its run method (WebSocketServer::run) that runs in a loop which posed a second problem of how to run asynchronous operation or how to do multi-threading in PHP before even solving the first problem I am facing. I tend to use this script but how could I run it without blocking other server operations?
I hope I have explained my problem enough for everyone to figure out what is it I am up to. Is it possible to achieve it in pure PHP alone? Meaning, no other frameworks/libraries, although I am open to use one if necessary.

You don't necessarily need to run the websocket program in PHP itself. PHP could simply feed the websocket server with data, and it can then distribute the messages. If you don't want to write or host your own, have you considered something like SignalR? Also PHP isn't great for async or multithreaded programming which is another reason not to do the websocket server in PHP (although projects like Ratchet have attempted this).

Also...if you already know C#, have you considered writing your web application in ASP.NET rather than PHP? That has even better integration with things like SignalR.

@ADyson I have a good head start in php and mysqli over ASP.NET so I prefer the former.

Websockets, as you've mentioned need to keep a connection with the server to distribute the changes. There are projects, in PHP, which can handle websocket connections. One of them is phpWebSockerServer by napengam.
Generally speaking, multi-threading and multi-processing is possible, there are functions and libraries (e.g. pthreads - which is dead or parallel and other approaches, which are described here)
Even though it is possible, it isn't common and I wouldn't use it.
Typically, when you build web application and you need to distribute those changes to other clients (users on website), you will use AJAX and some of those approaches:

Short polling - client periodically sends requests to server to check, if any changes happened. Server responds immediately with data or 304.
Long polling - client sends request to server, which then holds it until some event happens. Then it responds with changed data.
Or Websockets, which you've mentioned

(you could also use streaming or chunked responses)
Consider, if you need to deliver information about changes imediatelly or if it can happen with a delay.
If you decide to work with Websockets, take a look at Openswoole.
